# Spacemacs Setup Similar to AWS Cloud9 for Remote Development

Tags: emacs, visual-studio-code, cloud9, spacemacs, aws-cloud9

I recently stumbled on AWS Cloud9 and Spacemacs and genuinely impressed with both of them.

The problem is I cannot make Spacemacs to work properly on remote environment development just like Cloud9, all this time I was using VSCode with Dropbox and sync with local folder.

I tried with ftp, X window, dired remote mode (and similar Remote VSCode in the VSCode extension), none is satisfactory. I need it for all the full-blown features, remote code listing, debugging, versioning (I use mercurial).

Spacemacs is more than ok in the local development and I think VSCode just need to take a liitle more steps to rule them all.

Answer (score 0):

After trying numerous solution, Samba, NFS,etc, the closest thing to Cloud9 is [OSXFuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/), so you can use both Spacemacs or VSCode and get local development feels. But I haven't found solution for Windows, perhaps will be less complicated.